# Sqlite login authorisation failure

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I've written a so called 'error less' code but I'm facing certain problems whilst using the application.
Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login implements ActionListener {

    Connection conn1 = null;
    Statement stmt1 = null;

    Connection conn2 = null;
    Statement stmt2 = null;

    Connection conn3 = null;
    Statement stmt3 = null;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Window");
    JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel adminPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel engineerPanel = new JPanel();

    JButton adminLogin = new JButton("Admin Login");
    JButton engineerLogin = new JButton("Engineer Login");

    JTextField adminUsername = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField adminPassword = new JPasswordField();
    JButton adminLog = new JButton("Login");
    JButton adminBack = new JButton("Go Back");

    JComboBox engineerUsername = new JComboBox();
    JPasswordField engineerPassword = new JPasswordField();
    JButton engineerLog = new JButton("Login");
    JButton engineerBack = new JButton("Go Back");

    public Login(){
        //Establishing connection with database
        conn1 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        /*
         Setting up the startPanel 
         */
        startPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 15, 15));

        // Row 1
        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        JLabel loginType = new JLabel("     SELECT LOGIN TYPE");
        loginType.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        startPanel.add(loginType);

        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        // Row 2
        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
        startPanel.add(adminLogin);
        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        // Row 3
        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
        startPanel.add(engineerLogin);
        startPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        adminLogin.addActionListener(this);
        engineerLogin.addActionListener(this);

        /* 
         Setting up adminPanel
         */
        adminPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 15, 15));

        // Row 1
        adminPanel.add(new JLabel("Admin Login"));
        adminPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        // Row 2
        adminPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        adminPanel.add(adminUsername);

        // Row 3
        adminPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        adminPanel.add(adminPassword);

        // Row 4
        adminPanel.add(adminLog);
        adminPanel.add(adminBack);

        adminLog.addActionListener(this);
        adminBack.addActionListener(this);

        //Initial Visibility False
        adminPanel.setVisible(false);

        /* 
         Setting up engineerPanel
         */
        engineerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 15, 15));

        // Row 1
        engineerPanel.add(new JLabel("Engineer Login"));
        engineerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        // Row 2

        try{
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              conn1.setAutoCommit(false);
              stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM EngineerData;" );

              List<String> engineerNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

              while ( rs1.next() ){
                  String name = rs1.getString("Name");
                  engineerNamesList.add(name);
              }

              // Converting array list to array
              String[] engineerNames = new String[engineerNamesList.size()];
              engineerNamesList.toArray(engineerNames);

              // Adding array into combo-box
              for (String en : engineerNames){
                  engineerUsername.addItem(en);
              }

              rs1.close();
              stmt1.close();
              conn1.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e1 ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);    
        }

        engineerPanel.add(new JLabel("Engineer Name"));
        engineerPanel.add(engineerUsername);

        // Row 3
        engineerPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        engineerPanel.add(engineerPassword);

        // Row 4
        engineerPanel.add(engineerLog);
        engineerPanel.add(engineerBack);

        engineerLog.addActionListener(this);
        engineerBack.addActionListener(this);

        //Initial Visibility False
        engineerPanel.setVisible(false);



        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(startPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    //Method to convert integar array list to integar array
    public int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    //Admin login method
    public void adminLogin(){

        String adminUser = adminUsername.getText();
        String adminPass = adminPassword.getText();

        String adminUserDB = null;
        String adminPassDB = null;

        conn2 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

        try{
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              conn2.setAutoCommit(false);
              stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM AdminData;" );

              adminUserDB = rs2.getString("Username");
              adminPassDB = rs2.getString("Password");

              conn2.close();
              stmt2.close();
              rs2.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2){

        }

        if (adminUser.equals(adminUserDB) && adminPass.equals(adminPassDB)){
            AdminClass ac = new AdminClass();

            frame.dispose();
        }

        else if (adminUser.equals(adminUserDB) && adminPass != adminPassDB){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password.\nPlease enter again.");
        }

        else if (adminUser != adminUserDB && adminPass.equals(adminPassDB)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username.\nPlease enter again.");
        }

        else if (adminUser != adminUserDB && adminPass != adminPassDB){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username and Password.\nPlease enter again.");
        }


    }

    //Engineer login method
    public void engineerLogin(){

        String engineerUser = engineerUsername.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String engineerPass = engineerPassword.getText();

        List<String> engineerNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> engineerPasswordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> uniqueIDList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        conn3 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

        try{
              Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
              conn3.setAutoCommit(false);
              stmt3 = conn3.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM EngineerData;" );

              while ( rs3.next() ){

                  int uniqueId = rs3.getInt("UniqueId");
                  String engineerUserDB = rs3.getString("Name");
                  String engineerPassDB = rs3.getString("Password");

                  //Adding data from database to variables that exist in our code
                  engineerNamesList.add(engineerUserDB);
                  engineerPasswordsList.add(engineerPassDB);
                  uniqueIDList.add(uniqueId);

              }

              conn3.close();
              stmt3.close();
              rs3.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e3){

        }

        // Creating usable arrays from array lists
        String[] engineerNames = new String[engineerNamesList.size()];
        engineerNamesList.toArray(engineerNames);

        String[] engineerPasswords = new String[engineerPasswordsList.size()];
        engineerPasswordsList.toArray(engineerPasswords);

        int[] uniqueIDs = convertIntegers(uniqueIDList);

        for (int i = 0; i < engineerNames.length; i++){


            boolean condition = (engineerUser.equals(engineerNames[i]) && engineerPass.equals(engineerPasswords[i]));

            if (condition){

                frame.dispose();

                EngineerPanel ep = new EngineerPanel();

                //This ID is the identifier of the engineer
                //This will be used to generate data only for his particular project
                ep.setUniqueID(uniqueIDs[i]);

                break;
            }

            else if (i>= 1 && condition != true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password");
                continue;
            }

        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if (e.getSource() == adminLogin){

            startPanel.setVisible(false);
            frame.remove(startPanel);
            frame.add(adminPanel);
            adminPanel.setVisible(true);


        }

        if (e.getSource() == engineerLogin){

            startPanel.setVisible(false);
            frame.remove(startPanel);
            frame.add(engineerPanel);
            engineerPanel.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == adminBack){

            adminUsername.setText(null);
            adminPassword.setText(null);
            adminPanel.setVisible(false);
            frame.remove(adminPanel);
            frame.add(startPanel);
            startPanel.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == engineerBack){

            engineerPassword.setText(null);
            engineerPanel.setVisible(false);
            frame.remove(engineerPanel);
            frame.add(startPanel);
            startPanel.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == adminLog){
            adminLogin();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == engineerLog){
            engineerLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

So here as you can see I'm using sqlite data base. Authorisation for the engineer only works for the first engineer but now for all of them. Even if the data is right, it shows that user data is incorrect. The JOptionPane keeps on popping up even though after I keep clicking ok. After several clicks it just takes the use to the next JFrame although it said password was incorrect.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, if I understand your problem. You do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < engineerNames.length; i++){
  boolean condition = ...
  if (condition){
    // OK
  } else {
   // show error
  }
}
```

So you show the error as soon as you found a mismatch between the entered information and a database row. So everything is fine for the first object, since the first row will match. But for the second object, it will show the error, since you've entered the data for the second row, and the first row will not match. And then you "continue" so you never get to the second database row.
Your logic should be:

```
boolean ok=false;
for (int i = 0; i < engineerNames.length; i++){
  boolean condition = ...
  ok |= condition;

}
if (ok){
    // OK
} else {
   // show error
}
```

The `ok |= condition` is a OR operator: you want to see if any row matches. Of course if ok is true, you can have a continue to avoid looking at others matches.

But really why don't you use a query with the provided name and password?

```
SELECT * FROM EngineerData where Name=? and Password=?
```

And see if you get any result.

Comment: My friend could you edit my code maybe? I am truly confused :(!

Comment: The code I'm talking about is in your engineerLogin method. If you don't understand, try to debug through it, to see what I mean.

Comment: I'm unable to use my variable i then.
If I do what you suggested D: What should be done?